# accessing controls inside a datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, datalist

i am creating a datalist with RadioButtonList inside as a rating scale for each post desplayed in the datalist, however when i rate one post, all the other posts rated the same, can you tell me where's the problem, thanks.
PS: i know that the problem is in foreach loop whoever if i removed it, i will not be able to access the RadioButtonList or postIDLabel

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  foreach (DataListItem item in DataList2.Items) {
    RadioButtonList RadioButtonList1=(RadioButtonList)item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
    string choice = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;

    Label post_IDLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("post_IDLabel");
    int post_ID = Convert.ToInt32(post_IDLabel.Text);
    int value = Convert.ToInt32(choice);

    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("rate", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    string email = Session["email"].ToString();
    int course_ID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["courseID"]);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@course_ID", course_ID));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@postID", post_ID));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@myemail", email));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@rate", value));

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    Response.Write(choice);
  }
  DataList2.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NamingContainer` to obtain DataListItem.

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 RadioButtonList rad = sender as RadioButtonList;
 DataListItem item = rad.NamingContainer as DataListItem;
 Label lab = item.FindControl("postIDLabel") as Label ;
 Response.Write(lab.Text);
}
```